# Конвертировать string в DateTime

Tags: c#

Можете подсказать, как мне конвертировать строку `21.03.2020` в тип `DateTime`? Пробовал таким способом, но получаю ошибку.

```
string date = "21.03.2020";

DateTime date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string date    = "21.03.2020";
DateTime date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd.MM.yyyy", null);
```

Comment: А почему MM заглавными? есть причина?

Comment: @NasItaHighborne Потому что `mm` означает "минуты".